# Laravel PDF file cant submit

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, fillable

Itried to generate editable pdf file with laravel and then submit the modification, but i have some issue :

[image]

1- the value of the button is not showin 
2- when I submit  i have this error in console : `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 419 ()`

my view  :

```
<form method="post" action=" {{route ('inventory_quantity.update')}} ">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="submit" name="button_submit" value="Mise a jour" id="">
    <table class="blueTable">
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tbody>
           .......
                <td >         
                    <input type="text" name="reel{{$item->id}}" id="{{$item->id}}">      
                </td>                 
            </tr>
        @endforeach        
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

web.php  :

```
Route::post('/inventories/quantity/update', [InventoryController::class, 'updateQuantity'])->name('inventory_quantity.update');
```

controller :

```
 public function UpdateQuantity(Request $request)
    {
    //just for testing
        $item = Item::find(1);
        $item->upadate([
            'qte_relle' => 23
        ]);
        dd($request);
    }
```

Comment: Check in your browser if you're receiving a session cookie. This is required for the `CSRF` protection to work. Also make sure there are no empty lines at the start of your php files. The first characters in each file has to be `<?php`.